# How to make a nested list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, append, nested-lists

Suppose I have a 2 lists in my python script:

```
my_list = ['hat', 'bat']
other_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

I want to iterate through `other_list` and create a nested list for 'bat's that adds '_' + other_list item to a the 'bat' and puts it in a nested list:

```
 for item in other_list:
    for thing in my_list:
        if thing == 'bat':
            print(thing + '_' + item)
```

My desired outcome would be new_list = ['hat',['bat_A', 'bat_B', 'bat_C']]
How would I achieve this?
I tried the below, but it produces this: `['hat', 'hat', 'hat', ['bat_A', 'bat_B', 'bat_C']]`

```
new_list = []
extra = []
for item in other_list:
    for thing in my_list:
        if thing == 'bat':     
            extra.append(thing + '_' + item)
        else:
            new_list.append(thing)
new_list.append(extra)
```

Comment: How do *you* think this might be accomplished?  Perhaps write down the steps, or draw a simple flow diagram.  Please show your coding attempt and let us know exactly where you’re having an issue.

Comment: The code you added is not the code that produces that output (it would die immediately for lack of `new_list`, and even if you define `new_list = []` outside the loop, it dies for lack of `extra` on the first pass). Please post an *actual* [MCVE] that *actually* reproduces your problem.

Comment: Even with your edit, `extra` won't be defined, and you'll die with an exception before you see that output: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7BCoMwEETv@Yq9mVApSKGHQr5EQknpWgMaQ7Jg/frUGKPQvSzMzJtdt1A/2VuM4/IcTCCQ0Fa9pqqG6rUuxSzOh6NYN3kwhCMYCzvyYLCO6bIuZQazmga/5HWmi7S1pAqv7Qd5U9/FmT@Yq3YO7Zvvd9pGwQUCeW6E2NI4BDy58mjB0js59@9s7YI5byzxYooYfw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Add extra to the top of if condition

Comment: Apologies. I changed the format of the code to better reflect my actual need. It seems like I just need to check somehow if 'hat' is already in new_list.

Comment: Change your `else` to `elif flag` and add a line within that clause with `flag = True` and a line at the top with `flag = False`.

Comment: Why iterate over `my_list` if you handle each of the 2 items differently? What's supposed to happen if you have more than 2 items? Specifically an odd number of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> my_list = ['hat', 'bat']
>>> other_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> new_list=[my_list[0], [f'{my_list[1]}_{e}' for e in other_list]]
>>> new_list
['hat', ['bat_A', 'bat_B', 'bat_C']]
```

If your question (which is a little unclear) is just about reacting to `'bat'` with a different reaction, you can do this:

```
my_list = ['hat', 'bat','cat']
other_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']

new_list=[]
for e in my_list:
    if e=='bat':
        new_list.append([f'{e}_{x}' for x in other_list])
    else:
        new_list.append(e)

>>> new_list
['hat', ['bat_A', 'bat_B', 'bat_C'], 'cat']
```

Which can be reduced to:

```
>>> [[f'{e}_{x}' for x in other_list] if e=='bat' else e for e in my_list]
['hat', ['bat_A', 'bat_B', 'bat_C'], 'cat']
```

Comment: I like the list comprehension you've used here. Its exactly what I was looking for and its the most compact.

Answer (score 1):

I think will work

```
my_list = ['hat', 'bat']
other = ['A', 'B' , 'C']

new_list = []
extra = []

for item in my_list:
    if item == 'bat':
        for char in other:
            extra.append(item + '_' + char)
    else:
        new_list.append(item)
    
new_list.append(extra)
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is just my answer, but it seems to work. I think is clunky though, and I'm hoping for a better answer

```
my_list = ['hat', 'bat']
other_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']

new_list = []
extra = []

for item in other_list:
    for thing in my_list:
        if thing == 'bat':     
            extra.append(thing + '_' + item)
        else:
            if thing not in new_list:
                new_list.append(thing)
new_list.append(extra)
```

Comment: I think that's probably better and more flexible than my `flag` suggestion. Have you tried swapping the two `for` statements? I think that would make a difference if you were checking for multiple "things": `my_list = ['hat', 'bat'. 'cat', 'mat']`, `check_list = ['bat', 'cat']`, `if thing in check_list`